# random items from a list

Tags: list, random, puzzle

this is more like a puzzle. I wanted to know if there is a way to choose k random items from a list of n items, given that n is unknown, and I only want to read the list of items once.

Thank you

Comment: What if `k >= n` ? Will you get all items then?

Comment: Take the first k, as you  don't know them in advance, are random :)

Comment: n is unknown; however, assume k <= n holds true. The first k items are not random, it could be a sorted list.

Comment: There are a lot of people trying to help you. Next time, take your time and write in your question the full picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the answer to my question is this:

```
pick first k elements and store them into an array of length k
for each element x > k
   insert x with probability k/x
   choose position at random between 1 and k
```

Answer (score 1):

Easy (if k <=n). It is like getting a list of k numbers < n. This will be the list of positions of numbers to get. Create a list of range(0..n), get k random numbers from it. You won't have to read the actual list of items until the last moment. Obviously this is only useful is the final list of items is slow to read (it is read from disk or something like that).

To get the positions of items to pick just do:

```
import random
itemstopick = random.Random().sample(range(0,n), k)
```

If n, number of items is unknown, then you **must** start by picking the first k items (that is the solution if k = n). Then the only choice yu have is continue reading items and either choosing to keep the new item just read (and to remove another item) or to keep the current items as they are. To stick with a uniform probability you will have to decrease the probability to pick the last read item as you go on. Probability to keep the last item should always be P(k/n0) with n0 being the value of n at that time. I don't believe you can do better than that.

If you know some minorant of n (a value you can guarantee n is greater that it), just mix the two methods above. Start with a list created using minorant instead of n, then continue as for unknown n.

Comment: if n is really unknown, as commenters pointed out, what will you do if you do not have k items available ? The problem may well be impossible.

Comment: to sort things out, let's say I have a number of items of the order of a million, O(1M), though I do not know the number exactly, it could be 1M, 2M, or anything like that, and k is less than 100. There is no assumption about the generation of items, they might be sorted or not, or follow any probability distribution. The objective is to pop k elements from the list (read only once) such that each element has probability 1/n to get selected. I hope this clarified the problem settings

Comment: @Banana add that to your question, since it change A LOT your problem

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether you have the random values generated or not, if you do, than it is possible, if not you will have to generate them, and you will need around from 2*k to 3*k operation in that case

Answer (score 0):

1. Skip a *random* number of items from the current position in list
2. Take the current item.
3. If you've reached end of the list, jump to the start of the list and go to step 1
4. Repeat these steps k times.

Comment: I see several problems with this method. What does mean skipping a random  number of items ? Random in what range ? There is no such thing as randomly distributed values in any range. And step 3 seems to read the list several, which the OP does not want.